# Creating @Autowire like annotation for injecting properties

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring 3 and also heavily utilize the well known @Autowire annotation. I would like to create a new annotation, let's call it @Property that autowires Java properties from set by .property files or vm arguments.

Considering the following class

```
class A {

    @Property("my.a")
    private int a;
}
```

if the property `my.a` is present, the property A.a is set.

Is such an annotation maybe already existing? If not I am aiming to create one, as mentioned above. Are the utilities given by spring to achieve my goal? I think about creating a `BeanPostProcessor` ...

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already such an annotation - `@Value`

You should just define a [`PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), and configure it to resolve system properties.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

you can use `@ImportResource` to import XML configuration files. Then use `context:property-placeholder` to load properties

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/com/acme/properties-config.xml")
public class AppConfig {
    private @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url;
    private @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username;
    private @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password;

    public @Bean DataSource dataSource() {
       return new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
    }
}

properties-config.xml
   <beans>
      <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/com/acme/jdbc.properties"/>
   </beans>

jdbc.properties
   jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
   jdbc.username=sa
   jdbc.password=

public static void main(String[] args) {
   ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
   TransferService transferService = ctx.getBean(TransferService.class);
   // ...
}
```